# Why I cannot write "\0" to a file by fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

I'm learning how to use the header file of stdlib.h in C. Recently, I try to write "\0" to a file by fwrite, but it doesn't work. Who can tell me why? Thanks.

```
FILE *fp;
fp= fopen("abc.txt","w+");
fwrite("\0", 2, 1, fp);
```

There are only two blanks in the txt file:

[image: The result in the file]

But for other strings, it works.

```
FILE *fp;
fp= fopen("abc.txt","w+");
fwrite("ab", 2, 1, fp);
```

[image: The result of "ab" in the file]

Comment: You should consider using `"w+b"` in the `fopen()`.  On Unix, it would make no difference, but it might on Windows.  On Unix, you'd get two null bytes written to the file.  It also is not clear from your image how you know you have two blanks.  Do a hex dump of the file.

Comment: It's curious that you say you're learning to use functions from `<stdlib.h>`. None of the functions shown come from there — they're all from `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: What makes you think `"\0"` is 2-characters? Perhaps `fwrite ("\\0", 2, 1, pf);`?

Comment: why do you use a (stupid) text editor for viewing binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using Notepad. Blame Notepad for that.

Because when you open a file in Notepad, all characters that it can't recognize is automatically replaced with `' '` (space, ASCII 0x20). You should use a hex editor to view it and you'll get the correct result.

If you want a literal backslash and a zero, escape the backslash:

```
fwrite("\\0", 2, 1, fp);
        ^^
```